# Heroku Django Login Routing

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to make sure my url.com go straight to a login page and then route around properly. The issue is  Trying to follow https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial but trying to make it into a dedicated pages app which I am unsure of.

[image]

url.com -> should display login.html which is extended from base.html if user isn't signed in

pages/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**Think I need to change path here to something for base.html**

pages/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request,'registration/login.html')
```

So these two make up how to request the login.html from the url.

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY", default="dev key")
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '') 

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["url.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**Think the last two lines should be home.**

portfolio/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("pages.urls")),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

]

**Not sure how the url patterns need to be here** What I want to be using is django.contrib.auth.urls in a dedicated page app.

Currently only url.com/accounts/login works and url.com has a faulty login that does nothing.
base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Css Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'user/main.css' %}" type="text/css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Font Link-->
    <title>{% block title %}Base{% endblock %}</title>

</head>
<body>
    <main>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi {{ user.username }}!
  <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Log In</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you want to redirect the user to the login page if the user is not logged in right?

Comment: So the user visits the site and is immediately at the login page. He signs in and is then redirected to another page. There is a button to log out on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator, which will redirect the user to the login page if the user is not authenticated.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required. 

@login_required
def index(request):
    # now the index function renders the home page
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py you can put something like:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
```

and any view you would like login to be required for you can put this in views.py above the respective function:

```
@login_required
```

So for your index view all you would need is this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    @login_required
    def index(request):
```

See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/) for more details.